How to parse from a eabi .out file?
I have a .out eabi binary file and I'm trying to parse out all the symbol names, addresses, types, and byte sizes.
I found some information about this using readelf, but its not super clear to me whats going on.  It also appears that readelf is a linux script?  I found out that everything I need should be in the --debug-dump=inof section of the .out file?
Thanks!

The information that you want is available in the debug info, but it's not readily available. The amount of DWARF parsing that needs to be done is considerable.
readelf --debug-dump=info will give you a dump of the DIE tree, but then you will have to perform a ton of navigation and reference chasing. You could parse the output of readelf, or you could write your own parser with a DWARF library of your choice (libdwarf, pyelftools, gimli to name a few). Depends on what language you'd be using.
For a quick look of what the DWARF DIE tree is like internally, try DWARF Explorer (https://github.com/sevaa/dwex). Full disclosure: I wrote that.
EDIT: there are some DWARF parsing tools that convert DWARF in a binary into an easier to parse format (usually JSON). Here is one: https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/dwarf2json . This might be your happy place - all the low level debugging info in a format suitable for machine analysis, but none of that pesky DWARF parsing. That tool has a "dump symbols" mode too.
